# Post contents appear black

Tags: bug, android-app

On my Galaxy S2 (intl.) running Cyanogenmod 9.1, post contents appear in black:

[image]

Only for elements that are specifically styled differently, the text appears fine.

The behavior is the same for questions and answers.

Comment: I have now upgraded to Cyanogenmod 10.1.3 and the issue resolved itself.

Comment: I am having the same issue in the app version 1.0.2. What do you mean by Cyanogenmod? Since on the blog post about the release of the beta Android app it does not say you have to install additional software/apps. PS: I have a HTC EVO 3D with Android 4.0.3.

Comment: @fibonatic: Cyanogenmod is an alternative ROM (operating system) for Android devices.