# Viewing second achievement crashes Android app

Tags: bug, status-completed, android-app

When I open the achievement panel and select a post, the app pulls up the post without issue. But if I open the panel again while still viewing the post, and select another achievement, the app force closes. If I navigate away from the first achievement post before selecting the second achievement post, the crash does not occur.

<sup>using v1.0.40 on Android 4.4.3</sup>

Comment: Repro'd on my end, investigating.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fixed in version 1.0.41 coming out later today, thanks!