# Block quotes invisible on app

Tags: bug, android-app

Block quotes on Buddhist beta site comments are black text on black background.

Comment: What version of the app? There was a recent bug fix, try updating the app now and see if still happening.

Comment: Original bug report: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/234154/black-is-back-new-update-with-achievement-shows-black-backgrounds-with-black-te, looks like the same issue?

Comment: Problems fixed in latest update. Thanks!

Comment: Cheers, glad it's solved!

Comment: <insert joke about block quotes having encountered the void>