# Solid black rectangle after viewing achievements on Android app

Tags: bug, android-app

When opening "Achievements" then closing it, there's a problem with viewing questions and answers text, i.e. there's a solid black rectangle instead.

Device: Samsung Galaxy S Duos 2
App version: 1.0.50

> [image: solid black rectangle on question]

Comment: this looks like a pretty _solid_ bug

Comment: What device are you using?

Comment: @kasra samsung galaxy s duos 2.

Comment: Seems a regression from [v1.0.43](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/234154/black-is-back-new-update-with-achievement-shows-black-backgrounds-with-black-te?rq=1), but probably have been fixed on later version.